# Why are Server Actions not executing concurrently?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-action

Consider the following functions:

```
async function printAB() {
  console.log("A");
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  console.log("B");
}

async function f() {
  printAB();
  printAB();
}
```

the usual expected output of `f()` would be

```
A
A
B
B
```

as the `console.log('A')` statements can execute concurrently with the timeouts. Indeed, this is what we get if the functions are either both on the server (actions or defined in a server component) or both on the client. However, if `printAB` is a server action, and `f` is a function in a user component, we get

```
A
B
A
B
```

. Why does this happen? This behavior could cause lower performance if we use multiple actions at once, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: If all three functions are run on the server I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @code to confirm, if `f` is a server action, you're still getting `ABC`? I just double-checked `ACB` in this case.

Comment: I'm getting `A C B`.

Comment: @code right, it seems you have reproduced the stated behavior then. My issue is when `f` is client and the others are server, then it's `A B C`, and I don't understand why.

Comment: note: changed from `A C B` vs `A B C` to `A A B B` vs `A B A B` for better readability

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**; If you need to handle multiple actions, then create a single  server action to do this. Avoid calling multiple server actions in order within client code.

From react.dev's docs, we have two pieces of information that shed more light on the OP's question:

1. common [caveats of server actions](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server#caveats)

> Server Actions are designed for mutations that update server-side state

2. information on using [server actions in client code](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server#calling-a-server-action-outside-of-form)

> Server Actions are exposed **server endpoints** and can be called anywhere in client code.

These tells us one thing, contrary to how the OP may want to view it, when triggered via the client, each call to `printAB` is treated as a separate API call. This means that the execution of `printAB` as a function occurs on the server and not on the client, you therefore can't expect the same results you would if the functions were executed on the client.

As a result, triggering more than one `printAB` only causes the server endpoints to be called and when this occurs, we have the result the OP included just as below, but with more information:

```
// f is a client code
function f(){
printAB()
printAB()
}
...
// two requests are made, since f is client code

// 1st request
A (from first printAB)
B (from first printAB)
//timeout is invoked.

// 2nd request
A (from second printAB)
B (from second printAB)
//timeout is invoked.
```

**Final words?**
I'll say one way to look at server actions is to treat every server action you create as an API endpoint of some sort and trigger only one action per mutation and While it's possible and allowed, avoid multiple action calls as you outlined in your question.

Comment: I get that it's basically sugar syntax for an API, but an API can actually process things concurrently right? So I still don't get why server actions don't

Comment: Yes, an API can process concurrently. However, concurrency doesn't mean that the handlers (in this case printAB) are called at the same time. Rather, concurrency means that both tasks(printAB) can be in progress at the same time, and the system manages their execution. The order of execution is then determined by the time between requests, network latency etc

Answer (score 0):

from [react.dev "use server" docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server) (emphasis mine):

> Server Actions are designed for mutations that update server-side state; they are not recommended for data fetching. Accordingly, **frameworks implementing Server Actions typically process one action at a time** and do not have a way to cache the return value.

I still don't get why, and how it works in detail. Is this being done on the server side? Does that mean then if there's a lot of users, they won't be served in parallel by e.g. DB writes?